# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

Am trying to set up a sample spring-mvc helloworld program with maven. I did search for all the answers available in the forum but couldn't get the answer.
Below is the error am getting in dispatcher-servlet.xml

- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/
  spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of 
  the document is not .
- cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Below is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.crm</groupId>
  <artifactId>coll</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>coll Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>2.3</javax.servlet.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>coll</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

below is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

below is dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crm.bill.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

can anyone help me to know what wrong is in dispatcher-servelt.xml. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

On your dispatcher servlet, beans defination is not present. So add below on your beans declaration--

```
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Also, you need to give beans xsd version in `schemalocation` like below,

```
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

(I have given spring-beans-3.2.xsd version; you can mention any available version based on your requirement)

After this update, mostly you are able to run your code, but if still you face any error, then try to use `<beans:bean..` for all beans declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the specific xsd. In dispatcher-servlet.xml change the xsd declaration as below -:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

Comment: I tried even that. It gives the same error.After updating maven project.    schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/ spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Comment: why is it still giving error for schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd' and not schema/beans spring-beans-4.0.xsd' !!? Did you try the clean build ?

Comment: Am new to maven and spring. How to do clean build? I haven't launched this in the server yet